# Ubuntu upstart can not stop/restart graphite carbon-cache

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, upstart, graphite

I created upstart config file at: /etc/init/carbon-cache.conf to stop/start/restart carbon-cache process. I can start carbon-cache process using command: **start carbon-cache**, however, I could not use stop/restart carbon-cache and always gives me errors: "stop: Unknown instance:".

Does anyone know what seem to be the issue? Here is the my upstart config: **/etc/init/carbon-cache.conf**

```
description "Daemonized Carbon-Cache"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

setuid www-data
setgid www-data

exec /opt/graphite/bin/carbon-cache.py start

respawn
respawn limit 10 5
```

Comment: This is probably related on what the process is doing when it starts. If it forks, you should get the pid of the forked process and not the parent. Use ps ax | grep carbon to find out. There's special stanza in upstart - expect - which handles this cases. Read this http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#expect

Comment: I tried following and did not work as well: https://wiki.xkyle.com/Carbon_Collector

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using this carbon-cache.conf file: https://gist.github.com/dbeckham/8057390

Comment: The money quote from this file's comments:  
  
    # Fun fact, without --nodaemon, twistd carbon-cache forks five times (5!).
    # Upstart wasn't designed to handle that level of wtf.

Answer (score 1):

i think what's happening is that your upstart is successfully able to exec it, but as soon as it runs, carbon-cache, because of it's daemonic nature detaches itself from upstart. So when upstart tries to kill it, it realizes that carbon-cache is no longer attached.

Upstart expects the command run to stay in the foreground, not fork-off and de-attach.

"Twistd, the utility used to daemonize carbon-cache supports a `--nodaemon` flag that launches the process in the foreground instead of forking it into the background. At the time this [article](http://thecolinblog.blogspot.in/2012/05/supervisor-entries-for-graphite.html) was posted, the only way to get the `--nodaemon` flag to twistd was by starting carbon-cache with `--debug`."

Though, i'd advice against un-daemoning carbon, which is necessary in an upstart implementation.

Comment: upstart currently support 'expect daemon' but somehow I could not get it to work as expected. I would prefer not to use --debug.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo /opt/graphite/bin/carbon-cache.py start`

Comment: Hi @erbdex, I know I can use carbon-cache.py stop/start the process, however, making upstart to stop/restart is an issue for me that I have to figure it out.

Comment: You are dropping user privileges to 'www-data' user. And hence the carbon-cache initiation is done on that user's behalf. But carbon-cache needs root level access for initiating socket connections and sending men to Mars. Hence, use- """exec sudo /opt/graphite/bin/carbon-cache.py start"""

Comment: even use root, it does not help. Notice that I can start but I can not stop/restart upstart.

Comment: i still have a feeling that it is a permission issue. Could you please try replacing "setuid www-data" by "setuid root" and "setgid www-data" by "setgid root" to confirm. (And don't forget to remove "sudo", with root.)

Comment: changed to what you suggested, start is ok, stop shows me errors:# stop carbon-cache
stop: Unknown instance:

Comment: <root@ubuntu>-</etc/init>
# cat /etc/init/carbon-cache.conf 
description "Daemonized Carbon-Cache"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

setuid root
setgid root

exec /opt/graphite/bin/carbon-cache.py start

respawn
respawn limit 10 5

Comment: woo.. I can't put newline in comment!

Comment: I wrote graphite install script and tested on Ubuntu vmware: https://github.com/gdbtek/setup-graphite . You can try it out and see if your upstart can work. Thanks

Comment: Add these diagnostic details in the question. You can edit questions on SO.

Comment: """# ./carbon-cache stop""" What error do you get if you run this, on a carbon-cache that has been initiated via upstart?

Comment: # ./carbon-cache.py stop
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/__init__.py:3: UserWarning: Module twisted was already imported from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/__init__.pyc, but /opt/graphite/lib is being added to sys.path
  import pkg_resources
Sending kill signal to pid 15873

Comment: I can start/stop using carbon-cache.py directly. However, it's trouble for me when I use upstart to stop/restart

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41159/discussion-between-erbdex-and-nam-nguyen)